# In snap Firefox on Linux, where to put the files to lock preferences?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox

To lock down preferences in Linux, [I followed this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Locking_preferences): write the preferences down in a file called mozilla.cfg (or firefox.cfg), then point to said file in a prefs.js file.

This worked for me for quite a while in /usr/lib/firefox, back when Firefox was installed via apt.

(I'd like the settings locked down identically for the entire machine, not in individual users' profiles.)

Now that Firefox has moved to Snap in Ubuntu ... where do those two files (prefs.js and whatever.cfg) go, please? I tried a few things and it's not yet working.

Comment: BTW, Firefox (and Thunderbird, as well) is still available as packages from Mozilla. If you'd like, you can uninstall the snap version and install directly from the stable version: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/install-firefox-deb-ubuntu-22-04/ and https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: @DrMoishePippik thanks! That's what I did for now ... I did have to rename the prefs.js file (e.g. prefs.js.tmp) and then name it back again (prefs.js) for Firefox to notice it. Go figure.

Comment: Glad it helped. Though Mozilla packages have not been vetted by Ubuntu, they provide current updates. For that reason, and to avoid huge complete downloads, I've uninstalled snap.

Comment: Just FYI, generally speaking, Mozillazine has quite a bit of outdated information.  Despite its name, it is *not* operated by Mozilla.  Mozillazine is still quite useful, but I recommend double-checking content with an additional source before relying on it.